# Deriving an encryption private key from signature private key

Tags: encryption, signature

If I have a cryptosystem in which I require both signing and deriving a shared secret key for encryption, what is the recommended way of achieving that?

Is there any vulnerability in generating a private key and having the other private key as the sha256 hash of the first private key?

Or should I use the same keys for both signing and encryption?

Comment: Things depend heavily on the cryptosystem(s). For many (including RSA), a hash is not a private key, thus the question in the second paragraph is not applicable (the hash of the private key would be a secret key for a symmetric cryptosystem, but not a shared one). More generally, signing and deriving a shared secret key are different security functions and typically require different cryptosystems. Anything wrong with _authenticated Diffie-Hellman_, which derives a shared secret key on top of any signature system?

Comment: I was looking for ec based crypto systems. Having a ed25519 keypair for signing will not allow me to generate a shared secret using ecies right?

Comment: @pd176 There is a protocol for using the same key pair for public-key key agreement (or public-key authenticated encryption) and public-key signature using Curve25519/edwards25519, namely [XEdDSA](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/).  But it is not widely implemented or standardized outside Signal.  It would be simpler to just generate independent Ed25519 and X25519 key pairs—possibly from a common seed derived with different KDF labels—unless you are space-constrained for _public keys_ and willing to trade development and auditing effort for space.  So what are you trying to do?